# How to Load GWT theme Dynamically

Tags: java, gwt, internationalization

I have an application built on GWT with internationaliation. I want to load the GWT theme dynamically.For example:If (`localhost:8080/GWTApps/app.html`) then load this `<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>` theme or else (`localhost:8080/GWTApps/app.html&local=ar`) load this `<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.CleanRTL'/>`.How to achieve this dynamically any idea or thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the [gwt showcase](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/master/samples/showcase/src/com/google/gwt/sample/showcase/client/Showcase.java#L228) does it in the EntryPoint. just add these methods and call `injectThemeStyleSheet()` at startup

```
private native HeadElement getHeadElement() /*-{
    return $doc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
}-*/;

/**
* Inject the GWT theme style sheet based on the RTL direction of the current
* locale.
*/
private void injectThemeStyleSheet() {
    //you could inherit any style in your gwt.xml and change the whole theme by changing the THEME string
    //String THEME = "chrome" or "dark" or "standard"
    String THEME = "clean";
    // Choose the name style sheet based on the locale.
    String styleSheet = "gwt/" + THEME + "/" + THEME;
    styleSheet += LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().isRTL() ? "_rtl.css" : ".css";
    // Load the GWT theme style sheet
    String modulePath = GWT.getModuleBaseURL();
    LinkElement linkElem = Document.get().createLinkElement();
    linkElem.setRel("stylesheet");
    linkElem.setType("text/css");
    linkElem.setHref(modulePath + styleSheet);
    getHeadElement().appendChild(linkElem);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion(+1)