# GWT right-to-left internationalization example

Tags: gwt, internationalization

I am not able to find any valid gwt rtl internationalization example.
I have an application which I would like to work with any language ltr or rtl. I am able to do it for ltr, but what precaution needs to be done for rtl in gwt or how to do it, I am still not able to find it.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [GWT Showcase](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html?locale=ar_YE#!CwCheckBox). They do rtl if you change to an arabic language.
Its done in the [entrypoint](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/master/samples/showcase/src/com/google/gwt/sample/showcase/client/Showcase.java#L228).
Probably the same question is answered here: [How to Load GWT theme Dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669063/how-to-load-gwt-theme-dynamically/33675062)